# "[Class_Name] must exist" rails 5 rspec testing associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

In my rails application, I have Service, Request, and ServiceRequest models.

The associations are such that servicerequests belong_to both Service and Request.

When testing servicerequests with rspec, I have this:

```
require "rails_helper"

describe Servicerequest, :type => :model do

  subject {
    described_class.new(userid: 'bbogus', status: 'new', request_id: 1, service_id: 3)
  }

  it "is valid with valid attributes"  do
    expect(subject).to be_valid
  end

  it "is not valid without a userid" do
    subject.userid = nil
    expect(subject).to_not be_valid
  end

  it "is not valid without a status" do
    subject.status = nil
    expect(subject).to_not be_valid
  end

  it "is not valid without a request_id" do
    subject.request_id = nil
    expect(subject).to_not be_valid
  end

  it "is not valid without a service_id" do
    subject.service_id = nil
    expect(subject).to_not be_valid
  end

  it { should belong_to(:request)}
  it { should belong_to(:service)}
end
```

and in the servicerequest model:

```
class Servicerequest < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :userid, :status, :request_id, :service_id

  belongs_to :request, class_name: "Request"
  belongs_to :service, class_name: "Service"
end
```

Fo some reason, my test fails with this statement:

```
1) Servicerequest is valid with valid attributes
  Failure/Error: expect(subject).to be_valid
    expected #<Servicerequest id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, userid: "bbogus", status: true, request_id: 1, service_id: 3> to be valid, but got errors: Request must exist, Service must exist
  # ./spec/models/servicerequest_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How do I make my test pass the `Request must exist. Service must exist.` portion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your spec specifies ids for `service_id` and `request_id` here:

```
request_id: 1, service_id: 3
```

but these don't correspond to actual stored Service/Request models that are in the database - ie there is no Service with an id of 3 or Request with an id of 1. This is what the error message is referring to.

You can actually create these too, and the message will then go away.
eg:

```
let(:service) { Service.create(<valid service params go here>) }
let(:request) { Request.create(<valid request params go here>) }
subject {
  described_class.new(userid: 'bbogus', status: 'new', request_id: request.id, service_id: service.id)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked perfectly.

Comment: I had a similar error and this works perfectly. Thank you too!